# Drawrect not working (Java)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, drawrect

This has been driving me absolutely crazy. I can't get this rectangle to appear. I'm new to programming and I'm trying to recreate pong in 2D as a learning experience. Here's the code:

```
package ping;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Pong extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/**
 * @param args
 */
public Pong(String title) {
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    Paddles a = new Paddles(), b = new Paddles();
    a.setBounds(225, 25, 50, 10); b.setBounds(225, 475, 50, 10);
    this.getContentPane().add(a); this.getContentPane().add(b);
    a.setVisible(true); b.setVisible(true);
    this.getContentPane().addMouseListener(this);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Pong game = new Pong("Java Pong");}
```

And then the Paddles class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
public class Paddles extends JComponent {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Paddles() {}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0,0,0,0);
    g.fillRect(0,0,0,0);
    System.out.println("paintworks");
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(this.getY()));
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your rect is of 0 size. try g.drawRect(x,y,10,10);

Comment: @BevynQ: might want to make that an answer!

Comment: @BevynQ Second that, make it an answer please...cause I want to :P

Comment: A rectangle with no size does not make a rectangle.  A `Rectangle` will need some size (height and width) before it can be rendered.  Check the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for more details

Comment: Answered as community wiki.

Comment: 1) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 2) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Answer (score 4):

You have a zero size rectangle

this is the updated method.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(this.x,this.y,10,10);   // look at the api this command is redundant
    g.fillRect(this.x,this.y,10,10);   // as fill rect will overdraw it anyway.
    System.out.println("paintworks");
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(this.getY()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
g.drawRect(0,0,0,0);
g.fillRect(0,0,0,0);
```

Both of these lines indicate to draw something of no size. The final two parameters should indicate the width and height.

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for more detail.